# get values fron current column of DataGridView on keypress or keydown event C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, keypress

Problem:I want to get inserted characters(AccountID) in cell of datagridview, so that i can get respective username from database.
i had stuck in problem that on keypress event of datagridview, it is not getting recently insert char. For example,if user name is 'John Snow' its ID=JN. When I write 'J' in datagridview cell, and get value on keypress, it gets "". when I write further as 'JN', it gets 'J'. similarly, on 'JNE' , it gets 'JN' , so then i get JohnSnow from Database. In short, It get previous value not recently inserted.
I have Implement it as,

```
    public DebitCredit()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.KeyPreview = true;
        this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyPress);
    }

    private void Control_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the column and row position of the selected cell
        int column = DGV_DEBIT_CREDIT.CurrentCellAddress.X;
        int row = DGV_DEBIT_CREDIT.CurrentCellAddress.Y;
        DataTable result=null;
        if (column == 0)
        {
            string test = DGV_DEBIT_CREDIT[column, row].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();        
            result = getpro.SearchAccountByID(test);
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DGV_DEBIT_CREDIT[column, row].Value = result.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    DGV_DEBIT_CREDIT[column + 1, row].Value = result.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    DGV_DEBIT_CREDIT[column, row].Value = "".ToString();
                    DGV_DEBIT_CREDIT[column + 1, row].Value = "".ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First handle `EditingControlShowing` event of `DataGridView` as shown below. For the current control getting edited in the datagridview column, handle `keyUp` event as shown below.
Then you can see the expected result.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.KeyUp +=   new KeyEventHandler(Control_KeyUp);
}

private void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //YOUR LOGIC
    // string test = dataGridView1[0, 0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
}
```